# How setup Google Ads as source of Cloud Data Fusion pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to ingest data of my Google Ads account into a Cloud Data Fusion pipeline, but I just see that are only available 12 sources (BigQuery, Amazon S3, File, Excel, Kafka Consumer, etc)

Does anybody know if there are a way to connect directly via API? Or need I a paying solution as extractor of the data?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to ingest data from Analytics 360? https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/analytics-360/

Cloud Data Fusion does not have this connector but we will have this available in the future.

Answer (score 0):

An update, now you can go to HUB on the top right corner and choose your data source such as Google ads or Google analytics[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxj5i.png)